# Identification of Censored Areas of Talmud

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, writing-printing, anti-semitism, censorship

Unfortunately, the [Talmud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_the_Talmud) and [other writings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34097/the-fourth-exile-persia-or-rome) have been subject to censorship since their completion. These alterations seem still to be present in many modern editions of the Talmud.

How comprehensive is our knowledge of the censorship of the Talmud? Are their any  overt currents in censored parts of the Talmud that can / have been used to discover alterations?

For example, one of the instances I cited above interchanged *Min* and *Sadduccee*. As both of those terms refer to heretical sects (Min being early christian to my knowledge), it seems like, absent an earlier source, it would be pretty difficult to notice the change. Are other instances more obvious in some way?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/22221

Comment: @Efraim that source is missing important words from Rashi about the origins of the Catholic Church, Jon, and Simon Peter, on Avodah Zarah 10a

Comment: I'm sure, though not certain, most new prints, like vagshal and oz v'hadar include the missing Rashi's, and I bet dikdukei soefrim may also bring the missing words.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/talmudic-censorship

Comment: @DannySchoemann They are completely separate questions based on the same fact.  One is asking about the nature of changes and one is asking why we don't fix it.

Comment: examples http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26265/759

Comment: @BabySeal where can I see that Rashi?