# Chesronot haShas sources

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara

On a recent Daf Yomi, [Sanhedrin 107b,](https://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_107.html#107b_13) there is a long passage that was censored by non-Jews. It has been discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/), whether we should still learn the omitted parts or not. At [one such question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35333/) I've found a link to [Chesronot haShas.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/22221) Do we know what sources did the author have, when he compiled it? Are there other comprehensive lists, similar to an example in [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_the_Talmud#Text-criticism.2C_versions.2C_and_alterations) that compare the text variants of different important manuscripts?

[The mentioned work of Peter Schäfer on Wikipedia compares a few passages relevant for his work]

Comment: "Text variants" of which texts? Talmudim, individual masechtot, midrashim?

Comment: What's funny about that section in the Talmud is that there is nothing there to believe that the "Jesus" (or Yeshu) there is Jesus of Nazareth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most prominent and comprehensive works of comparative texts on most the Talmud is called [Dikdukei Soferim,](http://hebrewbooks.org/38520) by [R. Raphael N. Rabinowitz](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12500-rabbinovicz-raphael-nathan). At his disposal were manuscripts which included the Munich, Parma, Bodleian and British mss.

Comment: By chance do you know also which manuscripts were used to do Chesronot haShas?

Comment: @Kazibácsi regretfully, I don't. Never really went through it.