# PTIJ: Hadran Composition

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When we complete a masechta, we say the Hadran tefillah/declaration.  In recent years, there has been a great deal of interest in the composition of the Hadran as it contains information about the fundamental building blocks of Torah learning.

There are different versions of the Hadran, and the smaller ones provide less information, so a lot of research has understandably gone into taking apart the larger versions to try to analyse the individual components.  [In recent years, vast scientific experiments have been undertaken in this area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider).

What research on this topic have Rabbonim of earlier generations undertaken and what kind of results did they report?  Please cite sources where possible.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If a person completes a paper on one of the components, it is customary to recite a hadran alach hadran

Comment: the text is actually referring to the completion of the sing-song recitation, hadrone alach!

Comment: I once saw a guy finish a masechta so I went to go get 8 more guys but by the time I got back I guess he had ran because I couldn't siyum

Answer (score 7):

Gathering information on this topic isn't easy. Collider work (Hadron or otherwise) is a major hush-hush operation. Unfortunately I don't have Q clearance in the Pentagon (or any other clearance for that matter), but some advanced Googling skills have revealed that one of the prime collider ops involved the [PPA (פפא) collider](https://nuclearprinceton.princeton.edu/princeton-pennsylvania-accelerator).  Classic hadron sources typically refer to the members of the פפא team by codenames: Cha-9A, RAM-i, R. NachMN, R. AHA, Raf-RAM, ABA, Rach-ISH, Sur-HUB, ADA and Dr. U. The leader of the team is mentioned many times in the Talmud under the codename "R. PPA". There is one hint to the PPA team having managed to reach weapons-grade nuclear capabilities in a particular section in [Brachot 58b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.58b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "R. PPA and R. HUNA, son of RJ, were once walking along the road when they met R. Cha-9A the son of R. EAKA. They said to him: When we saw you we recited two blessings over meeting you: Blessed…Who has shared of His wisdom to those who revere Him, and: Who has given us life…as they had not seen him in over a month. He said to them: I too, once I saw you, considered you in my eyes as equivalent to six hundred thousand of the house of Israel, and I recited three blessings over you. I recited those two that you recited, as well as: Blessed…Who knows all secrets, which is the blessing recited upon seeing six hundred thousand Israelites. They said to him: Are you all that clever? **They fixed their gaze upon him and he died**.

The last sentence seems to refer to destructive nuclear capabilities unleashed by R. PPA and his mysterious partner, likely a foreign collaborator.

Answer (score 5):

One of the early researchers into [baryons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon) (a sub-category of hadrans) was Abba Sikra (nephew of Rabban Yochanan ben Zakkai) who was the head of the baryon researchers of Jerusalem ([Gittin 56a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.56a.15?lang=he)).

It seems that the genesis of the research program was the question of how to isolate [protons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton), a common, stable particle (which is both a hadran and a baryon) from the regular matter we see around us. This is described in [Zohar Chadash, Bereshit](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zohar_Chadash%2C_Bereshit.147?lang=he):

> אית לפרשא לון, ולמעבד פרטין דנפקי מההוא כללא דאתחזי
>
> They would explain to them, and make protons that emerge from generic, visible matter.

Answer (score 2):

According to many Rishonim, the *girsah* we have - *Hadran* - is actually a mistake, and was actually historically '[Hadrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian)', referring to the Roman Emperor. However, [this was changed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35333/identification-of-censored-areas-of-talmud) due to [Talmudic Censorship](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/talmudic-censorship). The missing Yud of Hadrian is counted as one of the [Chisronos](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/22221) [Hashas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86691/chesronot-hashas-sources?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The  real question is - why do we mention Hadrian at the siyum? This is indeed a mystery, although some have said that it for the same reason we talk about the [Ten Sons of Papa](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/22221). There is a  legend involving when Hadrian [executed the Ten Sons of Papa](https://app.lakewooddafyomi.com/browse/listen?type=other&id=233800001) in revenge for the hanging of the Ten Sons of Haman, but historians have found no evidence to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi AI.

The Hadran, recited upon the completion of a tractate of the Talmud (מסכת), contains several references and allusions to fundamental mathematical concepts. These concepts, while not explicitly mathematical in nature within the context of the Hadran, can be interpreted through the lens of mathematical principles. Below, we explore how certain phrases and ideas in the Hadran correlate with fundamental mathematical precepts.

1. **Infinity and Limits**:
   The phrase "לא נתנשי מינך ולא תתנשי מינן" (We will not forget you, and you will not forget us) suggests an ongoing, unending relationship between the learner and the Torah. This can be likened to the mathematical concept of infinity, particularly in the study of limits, where certain functions or sequences approach a value infinitely without ever departing from it.
2. **Set Theory**:
   The Hadran talks about the interconnectedness of all parts of the Torah, implying a set that contains subsets within it. This is reminiscent of set theory in mathematics, where sets can contain other sets, and the relationships and properties of these sets can be analyzed in depth. The concept of the union and intersection of sets can also be seen in the way different parts of the Talmud are interconnected and reference each other.
3. **Logic**:
   The Talmudic method itself is deeply logical, employing rigorous debate and analysis to explore legal and ethical questions. This method parallels the mathematical field of logic, where propositions are proved or disproved based on a set of axioms and rules of inference. The logical structures used in Talmud study, such as if-then statements and deductions, mirror those found in mathematical logic.
4. **Combinatorics**:
   In discussing the multitude of interpretations and applications of the Torah, the Hadran implicitly refers to the combinatorial nature of Talmudic study. Each piece of text can be combined with others in myriad ways to extract new insights and rulings. This mirrors the mathematical field of combinatorics, which deals with counting, arrangement, and combination of elements within a set.
5. **Recursive Learning**:
   The commitment to revisit and relearn the Talmud ("ודעתן עליך אף עתה לא פסקה") reflects a recursive approach to learning, akin to the recursive functions studied in mathematics. Just as recursive functions call themselves with modified parameters until reaching a base case, Talmudic study involves returning to previously learned material with new insights, deepening understanding with each iteration.

**Conclusion**

While the Hadran and the Talmud are fundamentally religious and ethical texts, the methodologies and structures employed in their study bear striking resemblances to mathematical concepts. These parallels demonstrate the universality of mathematical thinking and its applicability beyond the strictly numerical or geometric, reaching into the realms of thought, logic, and learning.