# Are there examples of Sasanian censorship in the Bavli?

Tags: christianity, talmud-bavli, censorship

The talmud Bavli was [compiled and edited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud#Babylonian_Talmud) in Iraq while Jews were under the rulership of the [Sasanian empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasanian_Empire). There are (unfortunately) [ample examples](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4170-censorship-of-hebrew-books) of the Bavli being [censored by Christians](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/talmudic-censorship) I would like to know if there are any known examples of censorship in the Bavli by either the Sasanian rulership or the Zoroastrian priests who held sway at that time.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34097/the-fourth-exile-persia-or-rome

Comment: If they did, they missed quite a few places: [Romans are better than Persians](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.17a.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), [Hurmiz pisses on Ahurmiz](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.39a.9?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

Comment: This seems like a hard thing to know.

Comment: What manuscript from before the time of the Persians would you compare it to?

Comment: One of [Prof. Elman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Elman)’s, OBM, oft-noted teachings is that the Babylonian Jews were intellectually safe, in contrast to Jews under Roman rule which understandably gave rise to The Church. It was (primarily?) the Christians who were highly sensitive to conflicting religious expression. This would explain the (complete?) lack of censorship by any other religious body than the Christians.

Comment: @DoubleAA not sure, off the top of my head, the Yerushalmi?